# use filter to return property values in an object

Tags: javascript, filter

Trying to make a function that uses filter but not a for or while loop or foreach function, that will loop through an array of objects only to return their property values. For example,

```js
function getShortMessages(messages) {
    return messages.filter(function(obj){
        return obj.message
    });
}
```

so if I call

```js
getShortMessages([{message:"bleh"},{message:"blah"}]);
```

I should get a return of an array = ["bleh","blah"] 
I'm just not sure how to implement filter under these guidelines. Also I was thinking of using a chain function maybe .map.

//// Here is the entire code challenge specification/////

Basic: Filter
 Exercise 4 of 18

## Task

Use Array#filter to write a function called getShortMessages.

getShortMessages takes an array of objects with '.message' properties and returns an array of messages that are less than < 50 characters long.

The function should return an array containing the messages themselves, without their containing object.

### Arguments

- messages: an Array of 10 to 100 random objects that look something like this:

```
{
    message: 'Esse id amet quis eu esse aute officia ipsum.' // random
}
```

### Conditions

- Do not use any for/while loops or Array#forEach.
- Do not create any unnecessary functions e.g. helpers.

### Hint

- Try chaining some Array methods!

### Example

```
[ 'Tempor quis esse consequat sunt ea eiusmod.',
  'Id culpa ad proident ad nulla laborum incididunt.',
  'Ullamco in ea et ad anim anim ullamco est.',
  'Est ut irure irure nisi.' ]
```

### Resources

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

### Boilerplate

```
function getShortMessages(messages) {
  // SOLUTION GOES HERE
}

module.exports = getShortMessages
```

» To print these instructions again, run: functional-javascript print
 » To execute your program in a test environment, run: functional-javascript run program.js
 » To verify your program, run: functional-javascript verify program.js
 » For help run: functional-javascript help

Comment: You want `.map()`, not `.filter()`. (You might want to read [some documentation about `.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).)

Comment: thing is, I am doing a javascript code challenge and they are saying I need to use .filter, that is why I am confused.

Comment: Either you've misunderstood or their question is wrong. `.filter()` returns a new array containing elements from the original array. It doesn't transform those elements.

Comment: They expect you to use `filter` to ONLY get messages less than 50 characters or less in length.

Comment: @codemonkey I updated my answer to match the updated question.

Answer (score 175, accepted):

Use `.filter` when you want to get the whole object(s) that match the expected property or properties. Use `.map` when you have an array of things and want to do some operation on those things and get the result.

The challenge is to get all of the messages that are 50 characters or less. So you can use `filter` to get only the messages that pass that test and then `map` to get only the message text.

```
function getShortMessages(messages) {
  return messages
    .filter(function(obj) {
      return obj.message.length <= 50;
    })
    .map(function(obj) {
      return obj.message;
    });
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rbbk65sq/

If it is possible for the input objects to not have a `message` property, you would want to test for it with `obj.message && obj.message.length <= 50` like this:

```
function getShortMessages(messages) {
  return messages
    .filter(function(obj) {
      return obj.message && obj.message.length <= 50;
    })
    .map(function(obj) {
      return obj.message;
    });
}
```

#### ES6

The same code samples in ES6:

```
const getShortMessages = (messages) => messages
  .filter(obj => obj.message.length <= 50)
  .map(obj => obj.message);
```

And if the input objects might not have the `message` property:

```
const getShortMessages = (messages) => messages
  .filter(obj => obj.message && obj.message.length <= 50)
  .map(obj => obj.message);
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/npfsrwjq/

Comment: it's weird because that should work cause i know it should, but when i run it under the program its saying typeError: cannot read property 'length' of undefined.

Comment: That means when filter is iterating over the objects, one or more doesn't have the `.message` property -- maybe some don't have a message at all? I'll update my answer with that variant.

Comment: I think flatMap may also work and provide a simpler solution

Answer (score 14):

Though I realize this thread is super old, I felt it necessary to comment in the event that someone stumbles on it again. I would do it like above just using es6 syntax like this:

```
objects.filter(obj => obj.key === 'value').map(filteredObj => filteredObj.key);
```

So the above example would be:

```
getShortMessages = (messages) => messages.filter(obj => obj.message.length <= 50).map(obj => obj.message);
```

Answer (score 11):

In case someone is looking for a single pass through it can be done with `.reduce()`

So instead of doing:

```
const getShortMessages = (messages) => messages
  .filter(obj => obj.message.length <= 50)
  .map(obj => obj.message);
```

You can do:

```
const getShortMessages = (messages) => {
  return messages.reduce((shortMessages, i) => {
    if (i.message.length <= 50) {
      shortMessages.push(i.message)
    }
    return shortMessages
  },[])
}
```

Or if you want even shorter hand:

```
const getShortMessages = (messages) => messages.reduce((shortMessages, item) => (item.message.length <= 50) 
    ? shortMessages=[...shortMessages,item.message] : shortMessages,[])
```

Comment: I really hope more people make it this far, I came here to say the same thing... much more efficient to use `reduce` than `filter` and `map`.

Comment: This is the best solution, although reduce is a little more difficult to completely understand for some, myself included.

Answer (score 9):

With custom return value (Simple ES6 Example);

```js
const customReturnFiltere = (result) => {
    return products.filter((obj) => {
      return obj.stock !== 0;
    })
    .map((finalResult) => {
        return {
          ...finalResult,
          info: 'product will be filtered if stock is 0'
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In addition, I am using ES6 Destructure with filter and compare two object array. And finally map specific fields those i need actually.

> Initialization

```
const bumperDealRules =[]; // Array object
const cartItems =[]; // Array object
```

> Final code

```
const bumperDealsSelected = bumperDealRules.filter(
            ({ item_display_id: item_display_id, purchasequantity: purchasequantity }) 
            => cartItems.some(({ id: id, action_from: action_from, order_qty:  order_qty }) 
            => id === item_display_id && purchasequantity <= order_qty &&  action_from == 'bumper_deal' ) 
        ).map(function(obj) {
            return { 
                bumper_deal_company_name_id: obj.bumper_deal_company_name_id, 
                from_amount: obj.from_amount,
                to_amount: obj.to_amount,
                discount: obj.discount,
                highest_limit: obj.highest_limit
             };
          });
```

Answer (score 0):

All answers are on point, EXCEPT for making the following assumptions:

1. The `messages` argument **is** an array
2. The array item `obj` **is** an object literal. If it is `null` or `undefined` you will get a `TypeError` exception
3. The `obj.message` property **is** a string. Possible scenarios where this is not true:

   1. `obj` is not an object literal (Number (integer, Float, NaN, Infinity), Array, Function, NaN, Integer, Float, Symbol, etc).
   2. `obj` doesn't have the `message` attribute
   3. `obj.message` is any other data type except string

In the 3.1 and 3.2 scenarios, `obj.message` is `undefined`

In the 3.3. scenario, `obj.message.length` will depend on the `obj.message` type

Here is a table for the 3.3 scenario showing the length check result for the most common data structures:

| obj.message value | obj.message.length <= 50 |
| --- | --- |
| `null` | TypeError |
| `undefined` | TypeError |
| Integer (e.g `0`, `1`, `-1`) | `false` |
| Float (e.g. `0.0`, `0.1`, `-0.1`) | `false` |
| Array (<= 50 elements) | `true` |
| Array (> 50 elements | `false` |
| Object literal | `false` |
| Function | `true` |
| `true` or `false` | `false` |
| `NaN` | `false` |
| `Infinity` or `-Infinity` | `false` |
| `new Date()` | `false` |

Table showing only the most common ones.

If your exercise guarantees the data consistency, then it should be fine to follow the above examples.

But in the real world, we should always do defensive coding (and assume that we cannot trust any data provided to us).

Defensive coding solution:

- Check if the messages is an Array, and handle according to your needs:

  - `return []`
  - `return null`
  - `throw new TypeError("messages argument should be an array")`
- Check if the array item is not empty
- Check if the array item.message is a string
- Check if the array item.message has less than 50 characters

```
    function getShortMessages(messages) {
      if (!Array.isArray(messages) {
        throw new TypeError("messages argument should be an array")
      }

      return messages
        .filter(function(obj) {
          return (
             !!obj &&
             typeof obj.message === 'string'
             obj.message.length < 50
          );
        })
        .map(function(obj) {
          return obj.message;
        });
    }
```

### ES6

```
    function getShortMessages(messages) {
      if (!Array.isArray(messages) {
        throw new TypeError("messages argument should be an array")
      }

      return messages
        .filter((obj) => !!obj && typeof obj.message === 'string' && obj.message.length < 50);
        })
        .map((obj) => obj.message );
    }
```

## Final note

If you want to improve as a programmer, you job is to identify the edge cases, and confirm how to handle those scenarios depending on the use case, or the defaults you / your team / your manager / product manager defines.

E.g. what if the `obj.message` is an empty string `''`, should you include it or filter it out?

E.g. What if the `obj` is not an object literal, but an `Error`, should you include it or filter it out?

```
    const test = new Error('This is an error with less than 50 characters')
    console.log(test.message.length) // 45
```