# Select a property from an array of objects based on a value : Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I have an array of objects with the following structure:

```js
var arr = [
  {
    "value": "abc",
    "checked": true
  },
  {
    "value": "xyz",
    "checked": false
  },
  {
    "value": "lmn",
    "checked": true
  }
];

let result = arr.filter(item => item.checked);

console.log(result);
```

I would want the output to be:

```
["abc", "lmn"]
```

Because those two `value`s have `checked: true`.

I have tried filtering out based on checked value:

```
let result = arr.filter(item => item.checked);
```

I am getting the objects that has `checked` property value that is set to `true`.

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your input's syntax is invalid. Consider providing a valid data structure. Arrays do not have key-value pairs, only values

Comment: Possible duplicate of [use filter to return property values in an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31201262/use-filter-to-return-property-values-in-an-object)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can use `reduce` and check if the `checked` property is true, then `push` (As pointed out by [assoron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57198332/select-a-property-from-an-array-of-objects-based-on-a-value-javascript/57198445?noredirect=1#comment100905733_57198445)) the value to the accumulator - there is no need for 2 loops:

```js
const arr = [
  { "value": "abc", "checked": true },
  { "value": "xyz", "checked": false },
  { "value": "lmn", "checked": true }
]

const filtered = arr.reduce((a, o) => (o.checked && a.push(o.value), a), [])      
console.log(filtered)
```

Comment: Faster than all the `filter` plus `map` answers for sure. But why use `concat` for this? Wouldn't `{if (c.checked) {a.push(c.value) }; return a}` be more efficient? Spread syntax afaik is kinda slower so that might be a third but likely worse option anyway.

Comment: @assoron Yes, you are right. I only wrote concat so you could write it on one line so as to be more readable. And spread syntax is horribly slower, I remember writing a JSPerf once and iirc it was 50% slower.

Comment: @assoron check this perf https://jsperf.com/push-vs-concat-with-reduce/1 - 94% slower lol

Comment: My ancient browser setup puts concat as 40% slower.

Comment: You can do it in one line with `push`: `(a.push(o.value), a)`.

Comment: @JackBashford I never knew this existed, thanks, that will help for a lot more one liners with efficiency too :P

Comment: No worries - I (ab)use the comma operator like that in a lot of my `reduce` answers now.

Comment: @JackBashford Are you able to explain how it works?

Comment: Yep - the comma operator evaluates all code passed, then uses the last one. So `a.push(o.value)` is run, then `a` is used as the return value of the expression, and returned from the function. Make sense?

Answer (score 45):

use filter and map:

```js
const arr =[{"value":"abc","checked":true},{"value":"xyz","checked":false},{"value":"lmn","checked":true}];

 const result = arr.filter(res=>res.checked).map(ele=>ele.value);
 
 console.log(result);
```

Comment: if you want unique values: const result = Array.from(new Set(arr.filter(res=>res.checked).map(ele=>ele.value)));

Answer (score 9):

Firstly, that's not valid JS - you need to swap your brackets and braces. Arrays use `[]`, and objects use `{}`, not the other way around.

Secondly, you should first `filter` out the wanted objects based on the `checked` property, then use `map` to extract the properties you want:

```js
const arr =[{"value":"abc","checked":true},{"value":"xyz","checked":false},{"value":"lmn","checked":true}];

const res = arr.filter(({ checked }) => checked).map(({ value }) => value);

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 4):

`Array.prototype.reduce()` might help you. `reduce()` callback takes two arguments, who's first argument is the old/previous iteration value and second argument is the current iteration value/element.

So using this function we can holds our current iteration values to the previous iteration value (total values).

> The [**reduce()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method executes a reducer function (that you provide) on each element of the array, resulting in a single output value.

```js
var arr = [{"value": "abc","checked": true},{"value": "xyz","checked": false},{"value": "lmn","checked": true}]

const result = arr.reduce((acc, cur) => ((cur.checked && acc.push(cur.value)), acc), [])
console.log(result)
```

Comment: only returns the last one of  (...)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `.reduce` to essentially `map` and `filter` at the same time. Below I have built an accumulated array using `[v].slice(+!c)` which will add the value to the (accumulated) array if `c` is true, else, it will not add it to the array (as `[v].slice(+!false)` will return `[]`, and `[...[]]` will give `[]`):

```js
const arr = [{
 "value": "abc",
 "checked": true
}, {
 "value": "xyz",
 "checked": false
}, {
 "value": "lmn",
 "checked": true
}];

const res = arr.reduce((a, {value:v, checked:c}) => [...a, ...[v].slice(+!c)], []);
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 3):

Fix the data structure and use filter and map

```js
var obj = [  
            {
                "value" : "abc",
                "checked" : true
            },
            {
                "value" : "xyz",
                "checked" : false
            },
            {
                "value" : "lmn",
                "checked" : true
            }
           ]
console.log(obj.filter(function(e){return e.checked==true}).map(function(e){return e.value}))
```

Answer (score 3):

Using map and filter function as below:

```js
var arr = [ {
  "value": "abc",
  "checked": true
},
{
  "value": "xyz",
  "checked": false
},
{
  "value": "lmn",
  "checked": true
}]


let checkedValues = arr.map((item) => item.checked ? item.value : null).filter(item => item);

console.log(checkedValues);
```

Answer (score 3):

Do not make the things complex. Just use a plain for loop and save the runtime. The following will iterate the array only once even if you have all the elements in your array has a checked property `true`.

```js
var arr = [{
 "value": "abc",
 "checked": true
}, {
 "value": "xyz",
 "checked": false
}, {
 "value": "lmn",
 "checked": true
}];

var results = [];
for(var i=0; i<arr.length-1; i++) {
  if(arr[i].checked === true){
    results.push(arr[i].value)
  }
}
```

If you look into this internal implementation of [`.map`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array.prototype.map)/[`.filter`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array.prototype.filter) they will iterate the array using a while loop. Let's say if you have a data that has all the elements set with checked true, then filter will iterate over all the elements once and again map will iterate over them to fetch the value from it.

Comment: Thats why I used reduce :) Nonetheless, a for loop is more efficient here.

Comment: @Kobe Agree...!

Answer (score 3):

All solutions here are valid, but if you prefer a more iterative approach with ES6+ syntax you can explicitly each-loop over your items in order to make your intentions super-clear for your readers (plus, it's faster than concatenating `filter` and `map`, as that loops over your list two times):

```js
const items = [
  {
    "value": "abc",
    "checked": true
  },
  {
    "value": "xyz",
    "checked": false
  },
  {
    "value": "lmn",
    "checked": true
  }
];

const formattedListOfFilteredItems = [];
for (item of items) {
  if (item.checked)
    formattedListOfFilteredItems.push(item.value);
}

console.log(formattedListOfFilteredItems);
```

Answer (score 3):

create a generic function in which you just need to pass the key value and array and it will filter out the arry on the basic of parameters

```
 var arr = [
          {
            "value": "abc",
            "checked": true
          },
          {
            "value": "xyz",
            "checked": false
          },
          {
            "value": "lmn",
            "checked": true
          }
        ]


            function filterList(keyValue, list) {
                let filteredList = [];
                for(let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
                    if(list[i]["checked"] === keyValue) {
                        filteredList.push(list[i]["value"]);
                    }
                }
                return filteredList;
            }

    console.log(filterList(true, arr));
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var a = [];
arr.forEach( (i)=> i.checked ? a.push(i.value) :null  )
```

It will evaluate the method passed in foreach for each element of the array and check if the element.checked is true it will push the element.value in the array a which is the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

You are not pushing the value in the new array. Try this it is working properly.

```
const arr = [{ "value": "abc", "checked": true }, { "value": "xyz", "checked": false }, { "value": "lmn", "checked": true }]
let result = []
let check = arr.filter((val) => {
    if (val.checked) {
        result.push(val.value)
    }
})
console.log(result);
```