# How to filter and map an array?

Tags: javascript

I have this object that I need to filter it.

```
let data = JSON.parse(this.getDataFromArray).map((x: any) => x.isEnabled === true);
```

I need to get in "data" only ID's of values that "isEnabled" is true.

Comment: Hey @ForkExe please try to research a bit more before you ask a new question. Since this is a very simple problem and has been answered too many times before, you could already find solutions by doing a bit more scrolling through the website. Here is one of them that I could find which points the exact issue:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31201262/use-filter-to-return-property-values-in-an-object

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Array.prototype.flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) to achieve the result.

```js
const dataArray = [
  { id: 1, name: "Alice", isEnabled: false },
  { id: 2, name: "Bob", isEnabled: true },
  { id: 3, name: "Charlie", isEnabled: true },
  { id: 4, name: "Dave", isEnabled: true },
  { id: 5, name: "Eve", isEnabled: false },
  { id: 6, name: "Frank", isEnabled: false },
];
let data = dataArray.flatMap(elm => elm.isEnabled ? [elm.id]: []);
console.log(data);
```

Please note that `flatMap` cannot be used in IE without a polyfill.

If you need IE support, use [`Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```js
const dataArray = [
  { id: 1, name: "Alice", isEnabled: false },
  { id: 2, name: "Bob", isEnabled: true },
  { id: 3, name: "Charlie", isEnabled: true },
  { id: 4, name: "Dave", isEnabled: true },
  { id: 5, name: "Eve", isEnabled: false },
  { id: 6, name: "Frank", isEnabled: false },
];
let data = [];
dataArray.forEach((elm) => {
  if (elm.isEnabled) {
    data.push(elm.id);
  }
});
console.log(data);
```

Comment: Okey, but I need to store only ID's , not all object

Comment: @ForkExe Then filter like this, then `map` the result to just store the ID's

Comment: @ForkExe: Updated the answer to use `flatMap`

Comment: nice never saw `flatMap`

Answer (score 0):

Try this to [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) first, and [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to desired property:

```js
JSON.parse(this.getDataFromArray).filter((x: any) => x.isEnabled === true).map((result: any) => result.id);
```