# How to convert returned values into in array - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, for-loop, concatenation

I'm new to coding and have been working on some example problems for practice...

For this question I was to to create an array of objects for 10 employees and assign them name, age, position, and salary. Then, I was to find the salaries of all developers. I was able to do this but, I  was wondering how to then convert the salaries to an array.

Code and what it displays in the console below:

```
const people = [
    {name: "bob", age: 20, position: "developer", salary: 120_000},
    {name: "susy", age: 26, position: "designer", salary: 140_000},
    {name: "peter", age: 33, position: "developer", salary: 220_000},
    {name: "cody", age: 51, position: "boss", salary: 400_000},
    {name: "franklin", age: 22, position: "designer", salary: 150_000},
    {name: "anna", age: 27, position: "developer", salary: 175_000},
    {name: "justin", age: 35, position: "developer", salary: 230_000},
    {name: "charlie", age: 23, position: "designer", salary: 120_000},
    {name: "tony", age: 38, position: "designer", salary: 210_000},
    {name: "ruth", age: 41, position: "developer", salary: 300_000}
];

function displayDeveloperSalaries(array){
const developers = people.filter(person => person.position === "developer");
for (let i = 0; i < developers.length; i++) {
    console.log(developers[i].salary);
}
}
displayDeveloperSalaries(people);
```

```
120000
220000
175000
230000
300000
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Not exactly how to convert the returned values to an array... I was able to push the values each to their own array like this,

```
[ 120000 ]
[ 220000 ]
[ 175000 ]
[ 230000 ]
[ 300000 ]
```

but I'm not sure how to concat these into a new array or what the best method is.

Comment: also: [use filter to return property values in an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31201262/use-filter-to-return-property-values-in-an-object)

Comment: (#kewl) you actually did 95% of the work, please check this line if it provides what you ask for `let SalaryArray = people.filter(p => p.position == "developer").map(m => m.salary);`.

Comment: Yes! Thank you! This is exactly it. I wasn't too familiar with array.map() before. I posted this in my answer so everyone can see the full solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding all the data into the array would be the best option.
Using *ForEach* function for iterating in the array and pushing the necessary data if the condition meets to the output array.

```js
const people = [
    {name: "bob", age: 20, position: "developer", salary: 120000},
    {name: "susy", age: 26, position: "designer", salary: 140000},
    {name: "peter", age: 33, position: "developer", salary: 220000},
    {name: "cody", age: 51, position: "boss", salary: 400000},
    {name: "franklin", age: 22, position: "designer", salary: 150000},
    {name: "anna", age: 27, position: "developer", salary: 175000},
    {name: "justin", age: 35, position: "developer", salary: 230000},
    {name: "charlie", age: 23, position: "designer", salary: 120000},
    {name: "tony", age: 38, position: "designer", salary: 210000},
    {name: "ruth", age: 41, position: "developer", salary: 300000}
];


function displayDeveloperSalaries(array){
    let salaryArray=[]
    array.forEach(person=> {
    if(person.position=="developer")
    {
        salaryArray.push(person.salary);
    }
})
console.log("salary",salaryArray)
}
displayDeveloperSalaries(people);
```

Comment: Thank you! I thought about using forEach too but I wasn't exactly sure how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) was made for:

```js
const people=[{name:"bob",age:20,position:"developer",salary:12e4},{name:"susy",age:26,position:"designer",salary:14e4},{name:"peter",age:33,position:"developer",salary:22e4},{name:"cody",age:51,position:"boss",salary:4e5},{name:"franklin",age:22,position:"designer",salary:15e4},{name:"anna",age:27,position:"developer",salary:175e3},{name:"justin",age:35,position:"developer",salary:23e4},{name:"charlie",age:23,position:"designer",salary:12e4},{name:"tony",age:38,position:"designer",salary:21e4},{name:"ruth",age:41,position:"developer",salary:3e5}];

const salaries = people.map(e => e.salary)
console.log(salaries)
```

And to sum, you can use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
const people=[{name:"bob",age:20,position:"developer",salary:12e4},{name:"susy",age:26,position:"designer",salary:14e4},{name:"peter",age:33,position:"developer",salary:22e4},{name:"cody",age:51,position:"boss",salary:4e5},{name:"franklin",age:22,position:"designer",salary:15e4},{name:"anna",age:27,position:"developer",salary:175e3},{name:"justin",age:35,position:"developer",salary:23e4},{name:"charlie",age:23,position:"designer",salary:12e4},{name:"tony",age:38,position:"designer",salary:21e4},{name:"ruth",age:41,position:"developer",salary:3e5}];

const salaries = people.map(e => e.salary)
const sum = salaries.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr, 0)
console.log(sum)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I see this gets the total of all developer salaries... I actually wanted to display each developer salary into a new array. Thanks!

Comment: @kewl Ah, then you could use the first code snippet to get an array of the salaries.

Comment: @Spectric I see. Thank you for your help! I was able to filter the people array into a developers array and map the salaries from the developers array. I posted the full solution so everyone can see.

Answer (score 0):

```
const people = [
    {name: "bob", age: 20, position: "developer", salary: 120_000},
    {name: "susy", age: 26, position: "designer", salary: 140_000},
    {name: "peter", age: 33, position: "developer", salary: 220_000},
    {name: "cody", age: 51, position: "boss", salary: 400_000},
    {name: "franklin", age: 22, position: "designer", salary: 150_000},
    {name: "anna", age: 27, position: "developer", salary: 175_000},
    {name: "justin", age: 35, position: "developer", salary: 230_000},
    {name: "charlie", age: 23, position: "designer", salary: 120_000},
    {name: "tony", age: 38, position: "designer", salary: 210_000},
    {name: "ruth", age: 41, position: "developer", salary: 300_000}
];

// Map  Developer Salaries
const developers = people.filter(person => person.position === "developer");
const developerSalaries = developers.map(e => e.salary)
console.log(developerSalaries);
```