# want to filter even index items of array multiply with the last item of array

Tags: javascript

I have following JavaScript code:

```
const evenLast = arr => {
  return arr.filter((a,idx) => {
   if(!(idx&1)) return (a * arr[arr.length-1])
  })
}

console.log(evenLast([2, 3, 4, 5]))
```

In the console, I get `[2,4]` instead of `[10, 20]` and I want to know why `if(!(idx&1)) return (a * arr[arr.length-1])` returns `(a)` rather than `(a * last_item_of_array)`.

Comment: You've mistaken map with filter. You can't map items with filter

Comment: i managed to solve using map but i want to know why filter does't work

Comment: Filter checks if the function returns true of false. If it returns false it will remove the item from the final array. Non-zero numbers are considered truthy

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31201262/use-filter-to-return-property-values-in-an-object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) is for reducing an array to a smaller subset. [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is for returning a new array. What you need to do is combine them.

```js
const evenRow = (_, idx) => {
  return idx&1;
};

const calculate = (val, _, arr) => {
  return val * arr.at(-1);
};

const evenLast = arr => {

  return arr.filter( evenRow ).map( calculate );

};

console.log( evenLast([2, 3, 4, 5]) );
```

Answer (score 0):

This should solve it:

```
function main(arr){
    return arr.reduce((total, a, idx) => {
        if(!(idx & 1)){
            total.push(a * arr[arr.length - 1]);
        }

        return total;
    }, []);
}
```

Why it happened is because filter evaluates the callback's result and based on what it receives, it either includes the item at current index or not. So your instruction in if statement will always evaluate to true regardless of which index, (an edge case where the item at index is zero) therefore only includes the item as opposed to perform what you are intending to